# regular expression is not matching with target

Tags: java, regex

Lets say we have a list of strings as follows - admin,sam1,sam2,max,maximus

```
Then in search box if I give 
     *a*m* should return admin
     *sam* should return sam1,sam2
     m* should return max,maximus
     max* should return max,maximus
```

etc.

My code is as follows(sample code, not looking into list) :-

```
   private static final String REGEX = ".*max*.";
   private static final String INPUT = "maximus";
   private static Pattern pattern;
   private static Matcher matcher;

   public static void main( String args[] ) {
      System.out.println("matches(): "+matcher(REGEX,INPUT));
   }

   private static boolean matcher(String filterCriteria,String parentString) 
  {
       Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(filterCriteria);
       Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(parentString);
       return matcher.matches();       
   }
```

Few more, with false output, but it has to be true:

```
  1. private static final String REGEX = ".*ad*.";
     private static final String INPUT = "admin";

  2. private static final String REGEX = ".*max*.";
     private static final String INPUT = "max11";

  3. private static final String REGEX = ".*sa*.";
     private static final String INPUT = "sam1";
```

Comment: I am not sure about your patterns, can you change the `.*ad*.` to `.*ad.*`?

Comment: Above comment indicates your mistake and solves it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seams that your regex is not correct as already mentioned in the comment by [staszko032](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50269238/regular-expression-is-not-matching-with-target#comment87556088_50269238)

```
.*ad*.
```

This regex mean :

- `.*` zero or more character
- literal `a`
- `d*` zero or more `d` character
- `.` any character

Instead It should to be :

```
.*ad.*
```

Which mean :

- `.*` zero or more character
- literal `ad`
- `.*` zero or more character